# Update values in R shiny DT when click on saved button

Tags: r, shiny

So I am trying to make a shiny app that acts as a calculator. So the basic idea is built on the DT edit function which I found [here](https://github.com/jienagu/DT-Editor). As you can see the screenshot below once the user clicks on the save button I would like to update the values for the column `TotalReach`  which is nothing but `impressions/frequency`. I was trying to do it under `input$Updated_trich`. But when I do it I get this error `Warning: Error in function_list[[k]]: attempt to apply non-function`. [image]

What could I be doing to fix this. Below is the code
server

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
## shinysky is to customize buttons
library(shinysky)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyalert)

rm(list = ls())
useShinyalert()
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  ### interactive dataset 
  vals_trich<-reactiveValues()
  vals_trich$Data<-data.frame(Partner = c("Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3"),
                              Impressions = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                              TotalReach = c (0, 0, .0),
                              Frequency = c(2, 3, 4),
                              Assumptions = c (.5, .5, .5),
                              pcReach = c (0, 0, 0),
                              #gg = c (.5, .5, .5),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  #vals_trich$Data<-readRDS("note.rds")

  #### MainBody_trich is the id of DT table
  output$MainBody_trich<-renderUI({
    fluidPage(
      hr(),
      column(6,offset = 6,
             HTML('<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" style = "padding:10px">'),
             ### tags$head() This is to change the color of "Add a new row" button
             tags$head(tags$style(".butt2{background-color:#231651;} .butt2{color: #e6ebef;}")),
             div(style="display:inline-block;width:30%;text-align: center;",actionButton(inputId = "Add_row_head",label = "Add", class="butt2") ),
             tags$head(tags$style(".butt4{background-color:#4d1566;} .butt4{color: #e6ebef;}")),
             div(style="display:inline-block;width:30%;text-align: center;",actionButton(inputId = "mod_row_head",label = "Edit", class="butt4") ),
             tags$head(tags$style(".butt3{background-color:#590b25;} .butt3{color: #e6ebef;}")),
             div(style="display:inline-block;width:30%;text-align: center;",actionButton(inputId = "Del_row_head",label = "Delete", class="butt3") ),
             ### Optional: a html button 
             # HTML('<input type="submit" name="Add_row_head" value="Add">'),
             HTML('</div>') ),

      column(12,dataTableOutput("Main_table_trich")),
      tags$script("$(document).on('click', '#Main_table_trich button', function () {
                   Shiny.onInputChange('lastClickId',this.id);
                   Shiny.onInputChange('lastClick', Math.random()) });")

    ) 
  })

  #### render DataTable part ####
  output$Main_table_trich<-renderDataTable({
    DT=vals_trich$Data
    datatable(DT,selection = 'single',
              escape=F) })


  observeEvent(input$Add_row_head, {
    ### This is the pop up board for input a new row
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Add a new row",
                          textInput(paste0("partner", input$Add_row_head), "Partner"),
                          numericInput(paste0("impressions", input$Add_row_head), "Impressions",0),
                          numericInput(paste0("reach", input$Add_row_head), "TotalReach:",0),  
                          numericInput(paste0("frequency", input$Add_row_head), "Frequency:",0),  
                          numericInput(paste0("assumption", input$Add_row_head), "Assumptions:",0), 
                          numericInput(paste0("reach_pc", input$Add_row_head), "pcReach:",0), 
                          actionButton("go", "Add item"),
                          easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL ))

  })
  ### Add a new row to DT  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    new_row=data.frame(
      Partner=input[[paste0("partner", input$Add_row_head)]],
      Impressions=input[[paste0("impressions", input$Add_row_head)]],
      TotalReach=input[[paste0("reach", input$Add_row_head)]],
      Frequency=input[[paste0("frequency", input$Add_row_head)]],
      Assumptions=input[[paste0("assumption", input$Add_row_head)]],
      pcReach=input[[paste0("reach_pc", input$Add_row_head)]]
    )
    vals_trich$Data<-rbind(vals_trich$Data,new_row )
    removeModal()
  })


  observe({
    # We'll use these multiple times, so use short var names for
    # convenience.
    c_num <- input$control_num

    # Change the value
    updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber", value = c_num)
  })

  ### save to RDS part 
  observeEvent(input$Updated_trich,{
    print(vals_trich$Data)
   calc<- vals_trich$Data 
   print(calc)
   calc <-calc %>% (calc$TotalReach = calc$Impressions/calc$Frequency)
   print(calc)
    vals_trich$Data <-calc
    DT=vals_trich$Data
    datatable(DT,selection = 'single',
              escape=F)

    saveRDS(vals_trich$Data, "op.rds")
    shinyalert(title = "Saved!", type = "success")
  })



  ### delete selected rows part
  ### this is warning messge for deleting
  observeEvent(input$Del_row_head,{
    showModal(
      if(length(input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected)>=1 ){
        modalDialog(
          title = "Warning",
          paste("Are you sure delete",length(input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected),"rows?" ),
          footer = tagList(
            modalButton("Cancel"),
            actionButton("ok", "Yes")
          ), easyClose = TRUE)
      }else{
        modalDialog(
          title = "Warning",
          paste("Please select row(s) that you want to delect!" ),easyClose = TRUE
        )
      }

    )
  })

  ### If user say OK, then delete the selected rows
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    vals_trich$Data=vals_trich$Data[-input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected]
    removeModal()
  })

  ### edit button
  observeEvent(input$mod_row_head,{
    showModal(
      if(length(input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected)>=1 ){
        modalDialog(
          fluidPage(
            h3(strong("Modification"),align="center"),
            hr(),
            dataTableOutput('row_modif'),
            actionButton("save_changes","Save changes"),
            tags$script(HTML("$(document).on('click', '#save_changes', function () {
                             var list_value=[]
                             for (i = 0; i < $( '.new_input' ).length; i++)
                             {
                             list_value.push($( '.new_input' )[i].value)
                             }
                             Shiny.onInputChange('newValue', list_value) });")) ), size="l" )
      }else{
        modalDialog(
          title = "Warning",
          paste("Please select the row that you want to edit!" ),easyClose = TRUE
        )
      }

    )
  })




  #### modify part
  output$row_modif<-renderDataTable({
    selected_row=input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected
    old_row=vals_trich$Data[selected_row]
    row_change=list()
    for (i in colnames(old_row))
    {
      if (is.numeric(vals_trich$Data[[i]]))
      {
        row_change[[i]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" value= ','"',old_row[[i]],'"','  type="number" id=new_',i,' ><br>')
      } 
      else if( is.Date(vals_trich$Data[[i]])){
        row_change[[i]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" value= ','"',old_row[[i]],'"',' type="date" id=new_  ',i,'  ><br>') 
      }
      else 
        row_change[[i]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" value= ','"',old_row[[i]],'"',' type="textarea"  id=new_',i,'><br>')
    }
    row_change=as.data.table(row_change)
    setnames(row_change,colnames(old_row))
    DT=row_change
    DT 
  },escape=F,options=list(dom='t',ordering=F,scrollX = TRUE),selection="none" )



  ### This is to replace the modified row to existing row
  observeEvent(input$newValue,
               {
                 newValue=lapply(input$newValue, function(col) {
                   if (suppressWarnings(all(!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(col)))))) {
                     as.numeric(as.character(col))
                   } else {
                     col
                   }
                 })
                 DF=data.frame(lapply(newValue, function(x) t(data.frame(x))))
                 colnames(DF)=colnames(vals_trich$Data)
                 vals_trich$Data[input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected]<-DF

               }
  )
  ### This is nothing related to DT Editor but I think it is nice to have a download function in the Shiny so user 
  ### can download the table in csv
  output$Trich_csv<- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Trich Project-Progress", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data.frame(vals_trich$Data), file, row.names = F)
    }
  )

})
```

**ui**

```
#
# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application. You can
# run the application by clicking 'Run App' above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
# 
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinysky)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyalert)
useShinyalert()
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Calculator"),
  ### This is to adjust the width of pop up "showmodal()" for DT modify table 
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                            .modal-lg {
                            width: 1200px;
                            }
                            '))),
 # helpText("Note: Remember to save any updates!"),
  br(),
  ### tags$head() is to customize the download button
 numericInput("inNumber", "Number input:",
              min = 1, max = 330000000, value = 20000000, step = 1000000),
  useShinyalert(), # Set up shinyalert
  uiOutput("MainBody_trich"),actionButton(inputId = "Updated_trich",label = "Save"),
 tags$head(tags$style(".butt{background-color:#230682;} .butt{color: #e6ebef;}")),br(),
 downloadButton("Trich_csv", "Download in CSV", class="butt"),
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears to stem from the usage of piping in this line:

```
calc <-calc %>% (calc$TotalReach = calc$Impressions/calc$Frequency)
```

Adding `library(dplyr)`
to the attached libraries and changing the line to

```
calc <-calc %>% 
      mutate(TotalReach = Impressions/Frequency)
```

allows proper saving to occur.

Comment: Thank you. I did  fix that but the edit option doesnt seem to be working. It should show the same options as add row  but it doesnt.